# Changing column order of a table definition using a script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bulkinsert

**The job**

I need to fix a broken bulkinsert by rearranging all fields in the targeted table, so that the order matches the definition of the bulkinsert.

I will need to do this on several DBs on several environments.

**What I could do**

Is manually drag and drop the fields in the correct position, that would work, but this would be highly inefficient as the fields are a total mismatch.

**What I'd like**

My job would be much easier and repeatable if I could create an sql script that does the rearranging for me.

With a script I would need to put in effort just once and execute it on all other DB environments in a reliable way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the table structures same across all the DBs? Please post your current structure and your desired column order

Comment: They are identical. It's a little more complex than this in reality, but basically the difference is: dev - acc - prod.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create a table with the columns in the correct order, move the data from the old table, delete the old table and rename the new one. Keep in mind that you'll need to drop and recreate all of the constraints on the old table.
Basically that's what the does when you rearrange them using the GUI.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, I'll see what I can work out.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Create a format file and use that to import data. Check this link for further reading - [MSDN LINK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191175.aspx)

**Option 2**

Create a view selecting data from your table, with the columns in the desired order. Now insert data into the view instead of the table

**Option 3**

Create a script to create a copy of your table with columns in the desired order. Move existing data to this table. Now drop your table and rename the copy.